# Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version')

Tags: android, admob

I know there is already another question with this title, but I'm getting the same error.
I've followed all the steps proposed in the solution but I'm still getting this problem.
Another problem I'm also getting is that the compiler doesn't recognise the attributes `'adSize'` and `'adUnitId'`. Here is my code:

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

<!-- Ad -->
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"/>

<activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

PS.: I ran this exact same project on another computer and it worked absolutely fine.

Any help will be much appreciated.